# How to properly access non-static repaint() method form static main?

Tags: java, swing

When i am trying to access repaint() method for JPanel form main static method I am getting error: `"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method repaint() from the type Component"`. When I tried to change main method as `"public void main"`, or remove static - it can not compile. What is the proper approach to solve this problem?

```
public class mull extends JPanel  { ...
....
public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel();

        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if ((e.getX() >= ringX && e.getX() <= (ringSize + ringX))
                        && (e.getY() >= ringY && e.getY() <= (ringSize + ringY))) {
                    ringPoints += 100;
                    allowedToDrawRing = false;
                }
                if ((e.getX() >= squareX && e.getX() <= (squareSize + squareX))
                        && (e.getY() >= squareY && e.getY() <= (squareSize + squareY))) {
                    squarePoints += 100;
                    allowedToDrawSquare = false;
                }
                if(!allowedToDrawSquare && !allowedToDrawRing){
//                  stop timer
                    // display points
                    ringTimer.stop();
                    squareTimer.stop();
                    showScores = true;
                    repaint(); // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method repaint() from the type Component

                }
            }
        });

        f.add(p);
        f.add(new mull());
        f.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I replaced all my code form main and there is one detail I can not see how to deal with. In my main method I created JFrame and added to it times (Swing timers). When I palced all code into constructor it does not work and makes no sense to call constructor itself while inside in (in order to add to JFrame Timers). How to solve it?
Constructor:

```
public Mull() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel();

        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if ((e.getX() >= ringX && e.getX() <= (ringSize + ringX))
                        && (e.getY() >= ringY && e.getY() <= (ringSize + ringY))) {
                    ringPoints += 100;
                    allowedToDrawRing = false;
                }
                if ((e.getX() >= squareX && e.getX() <= (squareSize + squareX))
                        && (e.getY() >= squareY && e.getY() <= (squareSize + squareY))) {
                    squarePoints += 100;
                    allowedToDrawSquare = false;
                }
                if(!allowedToDrawSquare && !allowedToDrawRing){
//                  stop timer
                    // display points
                    ringTimer.stop();
                    squareTimer.stop();
                    showScores = true;
                    repaint();

                }
            }
        });

        f.add(p);
        f.add(new Mull());
        f.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);


        ActionListener actionListenerRing = new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                  if(ringCounter < 3){
                    xRing = (int) ((getWidth() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));
                    yRing = (int) ((getHeight() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));
                    while( !(
                            (xSquare + squareSize) < (xRing)
                            || (xSquare) > (xRing + ringSize )
                            || (ySquare + squareSize) < (yRing)
                            || (ySquare) > (yRing + ringSize)
                            )
                            ){
                        xRing = (int) ((getWidth() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));
                        yRing = (int) ((getHeight() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));


                    }
                    setParamsRing(xRing, yRing, ringSize);
                    ringCounter++;
                repaint();


                  } 
              }
            };
        ActionListener actionListenerSquare = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    if(squareCounter < 3){
                    xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
                    ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
                    while( !(
                            (xSquare + squareSize) < (xRing)
                            || (xSquare) > (xRing + ringSize )
                            || (ySquare + squareSize) < (yRing)
                            || (ySquare) > (yRing + ringSize)
                            )
                            ){
                        xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
                        ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
                    }
                    setParamsSquare(xSquare, ySquare, squareSize);
                    squareCounter++;
                repaint();


                    }   
                }
              };


        ringTimer = new Timer(700, actionListenerRing);
        ringTimer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        ringTimer.start();

        squareTimer = new Timer(500, actionListenerSquare);
        squareTimer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        squareTimer.start();
    }
```

Probably, I should move Timers methods to another class and then call something like `f.add(new setTimers());` ....

Comment: Timer is not a Component so you can not add it to your Frame (f). Please describe your problem with the Timer because it should be ok like it is done here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing all your logic into the main method is a bad practice. It should reside in the object itself. That would also solve your static access problems. Here is how to do that:

Move all that code to another non-static method, for example `public void init() {}`. Then, in your `public static void main` method, call that init method like this:

```
mull m = new mull();
m.init();
```

Also, by Java [naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) Java classes use CamelCase naming. So your class should be renamed to "Mull".

Answer (score 3):

put all the stuff you have in your main method in the constructor or some init method of your class and then in your main just do `new mull()`.

P.S. http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm: mull => Mull

Answer (score 2):

`f.repaint();` (f should be final).

```
final JFrame f=(JFrame)e.getSource();
```

or

```
f.getContentPane().repaint();
```

Comment: He's calling `repaint` on `mull.this`, not on `f`.